# Uniform random sampling not returning uniform samples (Scipy uniform)

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, scipy, statistics

I'm setting up an experiment that requires 10 variables to be uniformly distributed between -pi and pi. This should be fairly trivial, using `scipy`.

Details:
Python 3.8.16
NumPy 1.24.2
SciPy 1.10.1

Note: The Python version cannot exceed 3.8.16 due to the use of the module `PsychoPy` which cannot operate on more recent versions of Python.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import uniform

uni = uniform(-np.pi, np.pi)
variables = uni.rvs(10)
```

This should return 10 values uniformly distributed between -pi and pi, however, it does not. It very rarely returns any values above 0, almost all of them are negative. For example:

```
>>> uni.rvs(10)

array([-0.03489156, -0.50000997, -2.98451371, -1.7355833 , -2.68861409,
       -2.03613316, -2.33966294, -0.52913401, -0.47277852, -2.27422887])
```

For experimental purposes, I need some of these values to be above 0.4 in at least some iterations of `uni.rvs(10)`.

But even when running:

```
i=0

while i <=0.4:
    i = uni.rvs()
```

The loop just runs indefinitely. This suggests to me that the sampling occurring using `rvs` is in fact not uniform at all. I'm not sure if this is an oversight on my part, or if the specific environment is forcing this problem.

I have tried to sample 10 values from a uniform distribution using `scipy.stats.uniform`. However, the values returned do not appear to be sampled uniformly at all.

Comment: How have you assessed uniformity? You may try a Chi 2 test or Kolmogorov, they are in scipy and this is exactly what must tell you if it is statistically reasonable to contest this sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html), you can pass `loc` and `scale` such that the sampling is on `[loc, loc + scale]`. I believe the arguments you are passing are being interpreted as `loc` and `scale`, hence you are getting uniform sampling on `[-np.pi, -np.pi + np.pi]`, i.e. `[-np.pi, 0]`. Simply pass `2*np.pi` as your second argument.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import uniform

uni = uniform(loc=-np.pi, scale=2*np.pi)
variables = uni.rvs(20)
print(variables)
```

Output:

```py
[-2.06319644  1.04916367  3.07400506  1.03832226  1.01205737 -0.57139507
  2.80455874  3.10886192 -2.18827084 -1.49833546 -1.54547847 -3.06877181
  1.15691104  1.48957702  1.36562556  2.69624898  0.03550638 -1.92457988
 -0.32644606 -1.9145792 ]
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I can't believe how trivial an oversight that was on my part, thank you for your input.

Comment: In general, it's good practice to use the size kwarg, `uniform.rvs(size=10) `

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to confirm an intuition, you can perform Kolmogorov tests:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(1234)

X = stats.uniform(loc=-np.pi, scale=2.*np.pi)
x = X.rvs(10)

stats.kstest(x, X.cdf)

# KstestResult(statistic=0.2799758081188034, pvalue=0.34631541108571073, statistic_location=1.759139883937797, statistic_sign=-1)
```

We don't reject H0, we may assume the sample (even as small as 10) comes from the distribution.

If you check against your first definition:

```
Xbad = stats.uniform(loc=-np.pi, scale=np.pi)
stats.kstest(x, Xbad.cdf)

# KstestResult(statistic=0.6, pvalue=0.0005681672000000005, statistic_location=0.7672320360752276, statistic_sign=-1)
```

We can reject H0 with risk less than 0.1% of being wrong. Which confirm your observation, your configuration was not uniform on the domain you expected.

Always comforting to confirm statistically scipy is working as expected.